# How to show the bottom of a dynamically growing HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML page is dynamically growing by new content at the bottom, every few seconds. I want the user to see the bottom of the page, always. Is it possible to do it with jQuery? I tried this snippet every 100 milliseconds, doesn't work properly:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 500);
```

Comment: You could put an element at the very end but before the updating container & .scrollTo() it with easing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  setInterval(function(){
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 100);
  },100);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/DBzNR/2/)

Comment: in your jsFiddle example change put lines into the page every 100 msec (instead of 500) and you will see the problem (in Google Chrome)